# Fiddler extension and inspectors in same assembly

Tags: fiddler, fiddler-dev

I'm trying to create a fiddler Inspector2 and IFiddlerExtension in the same assembly. However, I can't get the extension to load if I host the assembly in the /Fiddler2/Inspectors/ folder and the inspector won't load when hosted in the /Fiddler2/Scripts assembly. Alternately, is there a way to manually inject, let's say, the inspector in the OnLoad code in the extension (or vice versa)?

I suspect the answer is no, but does someone know if it is possible to get Fiddler to load both types from the same assembly?

**Background:**
I'd like to be able to provide an inspector that will provide some visualization of a given response, while an extension hosts a new tab that will configure and provide analysis over the entire set of sessions.

If I need separate assemblies, I will likely need three since I'll have common code factored into a shared assembly and then the two assemblies to be put in different locations. It's a lot of extra work for a small assembly with only a handful of types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct to note that Fiddler's partitioning of extension types makes it difficult to offer both FiddlerExtensions and Inspectors in a single assembly today.

Technically, there's nothing stopping your Inspector object from manually creating and managing a top-level tab, since the primary point of the `IFiddlerExtension` interface is to get your code loaded in the first place, and Inspectors are already loaded anyway.

In the future, this *could* conceivably be problematic as I hope to offer "delay-loaded" extension types, but that feature would almost certainly be opt-in and thus not likely to break you.